# Add Visual Composer Template to wordpress php template file

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, visual-composer

The website I am working on has a complex footer that has been created in Visual Composer as a template. Rather than having to drag and drop the template file on every page we would like to hook this file into the footer.php theme file. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished? Is there a shortcode?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? This isn't a "do it for me" site.

Comment: I was simply asking if anyone was aware of a shortcode that could be used for this situation or if anyone knew of an alternative to adding VC templates to a php template file. I have read through VC documentation but couldn't find an answer, hence asking here.

Comment: Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). It is expected that you research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.